# Is there a way to swap objects of different types?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am wondering if there is a way to swap two objects of different types in Swift.

Here is my trial:

```
func swapXY<T>(inout first: T,intout second: T)
{
    (first ,second  ) = ( second,  first)
}
```

Let's say I want the two parameters to be T,Y respectively. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What you want to do makes no sense. Even if you could make a Crocodile object refer to a Trampoline object, doing so can only lead to tears.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths actually I want to swap the object along with their types , so after swapping ( first will have the type Y)

Comment: Again, this makes no sense. What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I am not facing any problem to solve , just asking why l can't do such a generic function. This might be helpful for someone sooner or later.

Comment: You can't do it because no function is capable of going back and rewriting the code in the calling function to make your variables refer to different types. "Swapping types" simply isn't meaningful in a statically typed language, outside of casting between types having a common supertype. The best you can do is something with `AnyObject`, which almost certainly isn't the right solution, and for which your original swap function will in any case work, since there's only one type involved.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths this is good explanation, so R U saying the main challenge here is that the variable can't change its type after it's being initialized?

Comment: It's not a "challenge", it's a design feature of the language. The type of a variable is determined when it is declared, so it is set even before it is initialized, notwithstanding the fact that the Swift compiler can infer the type from the value you use to initialize it if you do so at the point of declaration.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths thank you, I will accept the combination of ur comments as an answer later today if no one disproves it.

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can swap two items, and the function is already included in the standard library.

```
swap(_:_:)

Exchange the values of a and b.
Declaration

func swap<T>(inout _ a: T, inout _ b: T)
```

[Swift Standard Library Functions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:FSs4swapurFTRq_Rq__T_)

However, if they are not the same type, then no, you cannot swap two items of different types.

**Swift 3**

```
func swap<swapType>( _ a: inout swapType, _ b: inout swapType) {
  (a, b) = (b, a)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is a much more specific swap of classes inheriting from a common ancestor:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog: Animal {}
class Cat: Animal {}

// Note that cat and dog are both variables of type `Animal`, 
// even though their types are different subclasses of `Animal`.
var cat: Animal = Cat()
var dog: Animal = Dog()

print("cat: \(cat)")
print("dog: \(dog)")

swap(&dog, &cat) // use the standard Swift swap function.

print("After swap:")
print("cat: \(cat)")
print("dog: \(dog)")
```

The above code works because `cat` and `dog` are both "is-a" `Animal`, both before and after the swap. Swapping objects of unrelated types, however, cannot be done in Swift, nor does it really make sense:

```
var dog = Dog() // dog is of type Dog, NOT Animal
var cat = Cat() // cat is of type Cat, NOT Animal
swap(&cat, &dog) // Compile error!
```

This code won't compile because a variable of type `Dog` cannot hold a value of type `Cat` in Swift or any other strongly-typed language.

Answer (score 1):

on first sight it looks terrible, on the second sight ... it could be sometimes very useful function

```
import Foundation

let a: (Int, String) = (1,"alfa")
let b: (Bool, NSDate) = (true, NSDate())

func foo<A,B>(t: (A,B))->(B,A) {
    return (t.1,t.0)
}

print(a, foo(a))    // (1, "alfa") ("alfa", 1)
print(b, foo(b))    // (true, 2015-11-22 21:50:21 +0000) (2015-11-22 21:50:21 +0000, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 10
var b = 20 
print("A", a)
print("B",b)
a = a + b;//a=30 (10+20)
b = a - b;//b=10 (30-20)
a = a - b;//a=20 (30-10)
print("A",a)
print("B",b)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

use  the **`swapAt()`** method

provide two indexes inside your array, and the items at those positions will be swapped.

For example, consider this array:

```
var names = ["Paul", "John", "George", "Ringo"]
```

If I wanted **John** and **Paul** to swap places, I’d swap positions 0 and 1, like this:

```
names.swapAt(0, 1)
```

Find the developer documentation here

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2893281-swapat